# How to reload a UIDatePicker after changing the date picker mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an UIDatePicker and want to change it's mode on the fly. Basically I have to table view cells, one with the date and another with the time. When I select the first row I want the date picker to display in UIDatePickerModeDate and for the second row it should display in UIDatePickerModeTime.

The UIPickerView provides a reloadAllComponents method, which the date picker does not. So I am kinda of stuck here.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UIDatePicker` conforms to the `UIResponder` protocol which has a `reloadInputViews` method:

`[myDatePicker reloadInputViews];`